Migrate NuGet packages into GitHub Packages
I would like to migrate the NuGet packages from my internal NuGet feeds into GitHub packages.
My idea is to create a new GitHub repository and link all the NuGet packages here.
In the GitHub documentation i can find how to link the package during creation. By specifying the RepositoryUrl in the Nuspec or csproj.
In my case the nupkg is already created.
Is there a way using NuGet CLI or dotnet nuget push to push an existing package and link it to a GitHub repository?
